# data source location

Tags: grails

I'm currently working with the Grails tool suit with eclipse. I created an an application, defined a domain class and my app works great. My question is, when I deploy my war file how is the database stored? Do I link my data source file to an sql database url. If so upon running my app the first time does Grails create the database for you? You probably understand my question by now. How does this work?

I've looked at this documentation and cant find how grails goes about with creating the database I defined.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, with the exception of H2 Grails does not setup your database. You will need to setup the database, and configure your datasource to connect to the database.

That said, Grails will manage (as best it can) the schema for your database based upon your Domain classes. This is the default behavior when `dbCreate` is set to "*update*" in your `DataSource.groovy` file.

I would recommend reading through the great online [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource) regarding database configuration and settings.

You also have more advanced tools available to you such as the [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) should you need that level of control and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

In DataSource.groovy (under the conf dir) you find the definition of a H2 db. You could configure a mysql db, oracle, mongodb and so on database.
You also could specify which database use in dev, test and prod enviroments.

Answer (score 1):

when you run your default rails app. The grails environment creates a in memory database for your app. It is created every time you restart your project.

In case you want to have your persistent database like mysql, mongodb etc.
What you need to do is (mysql for example)

1. Add a mysql dependency in BuildConfig.groovy  like `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'`
2. `Add Database and driver settings in DataSource.groovy`. Now you can have different databases for different environments i.e. prod, test and dev modes. You can do this by having global setting for database or by defining settings for each mode separately.

In order to view your database from your running app you can use link `http://localhost:8080/app/dbconsole` just enter your database password and username. You will be able to do all your db related queries here. In case you are using grails default in memory database just use hit enter the default values that are there in DataSource.groovy for database